# Merging two Fancybox scripts together and fixing the buttons

Tags: jquery, fancybox, sharing

I am using Fancybox with in the title attribute social media sharing buttons. I got it working from [this](http://jsfiddle.net/B9ytK/202/) example. [Here's](http://jsfiddle.net/dagloser/B9ytK/207/) what I have now.

But now I have two problems left. Now I am using two scripts I need to merge together AND get everything to work like normal, but when I remove the line

```
$('.fancybox').fancybox();
```

from the Fancybox script, the sharing button shows up, but all the buttons disappear. You can still flip through the images with the arrow keys though. But when I keep that line the sharing button won't show up.

The fancybox script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        /*
         *  Simple image gallery. Uses default settings
         */

        $('.fancybox').fancybox();

        /* Using custom settings */

        $("a#inline").fancybox({
            'hideOnContentClick': false
        });

        /*
         *  Different effects
         */

        // Change title type, overlay opening speed and opacity
        $(".fancybox-effects-a").fancybox({
            helpers: {
                title : {
                    type : 'outside'
                },
                overlay : {
                    speedIn : 500,
                    opacity : 0.75
                }
            }
        });

        // Disable opening and closing animations, change title type
        $(".fancybox-effects-b").fancybox({
            openEffect  : 'none',
            closeEffect : 'none',

            helpers : {
                title : {
                    type : 'over'
                }
            }
        });

        // Set custom style, close if clicked, change title type and overlay color
        $(".fancybox-effects-c").fancybox({
            wrapCSS    : 'fancybox-custom',
            closeClick : true,

            helpers : {
                title : {
                    type : 'inside'
                },
                overlay : {
                    css : {
                        'background-color' : '#eee'
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        // Remove padding, set opening and closing animations, close if clicked and disable overlay
        $(".fancybox-effects-d").fancybox({
            padding: 0,

            openEffect : 'elastic',
            openSpeed  : 150,

            closeEffect : 'elastic',
            closeSpeed  : 150,

            closeClick : true,

            helpers : {
                overlay : null
            }
        });

        /*
         *  Button helper. Disable animations, hide close button, change title type and content
         */

        $('.fancybox-buttons').fancybox({
            openEffect  : 'none',
            closeEffect : 'none',

            prevEffect : 'none',
            nextEffect : 'none',

            closeBtn  : false,
            helpers : {
                title : {
                    type : 'inside'
                },
                buttons : {}
            },

            afterLoad : function() {
                this.title = 'Image ' + (this.index + 1) + ' of ' + this.group.length + (this.title ? ' - ' + this.title : '');
            }
        });

    });
</script>
```

And here is the script for the sharing buttons:

```
<script>
//<![CDATA[ 

$(".fancybox")
.attr('rel', 'gallery')
.fancybox({
    beforeShow: function () {
        if (this.title) {
            // New line
            this.title += '<br />';

            // Add FaceBook like button
            this.title += '<iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=' + this.href + '&amp;layout=button_count&amp;show_faces=true&amp;width=500&amp;action=like&amp;font&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;height=23" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:110px; height:23px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>';
        }
    },
    afterShow: function() {
        // Render tweet button
        twttr.widgets.load();
    }
});

//]]> 
</script>
```

Comment: Can you put this on http://jsfiddle.net/, it will be easier to solve

Comment: @Oritm Ofourse, Here's the [link](http://jsfiddle.net/dagloser/B9ytK/207/) :)

Comment: Im going to check it out